# How to go over JSON in JS

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I'm developing an Ajax query to Django and works fine, returns the correct value but when I want to access the info I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
```

I returned the information query with these lines in python file:

```
attributes = MyModel._meta.get_fields()
objects = MyModel.objects.all()
data = serializers.serialize('json', objects, fields=(attributes[1].name))
print(data)

return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

print(data) output:

```
[{
  "model": "contenttypes.contenttype",
  "pk": 11,
  "fields": {
    "model": "accountingseat"}
  },
{
  "model": "contenttypes.contenttype",
  "pk": 12,
  "fields": {
    "model": "bill"
  }
}]
```

javascript file:

```
function functionName(param) {
  for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
    console.log(param[i]);
    console.log(param[i].pk);
    var fields = param[i]['fields'];
    for (var x = 0; x < fields.length; x++) {
      console.log(fields.[x]); //error line
    }
  }
}
```

console.log() output:

```
Object { model: "general.module", pk: 1, fields: { name: "General" } }
```

The problem is that I can't access with *name* because name of attribute change in each model.

How can i access to fields? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fields` is an object. Look up how to loop over the keys/values of an object.

Comment: @DacreDenny `console.log(fields[x]);`don't enter inside second loop

Comment: @FrankModica could you tell me how to loop over fields object ? I'm new in javascript.

Comment: @AlbertoSanmartinMartinez just a friendly mention that answers can be accepted by clicking the "grey tick" next to that answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this can be resolved by using `Object.values()` like so:

```
function functionName(param) {
  for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
    console.log(param[i]);
    console.log(param[i].pk);

    var fields = param[i]['fields'];

    // Object.values throws expection if undefined passed so check this first
    if(fields) {

        // Access the values of the fields object if valid
        var fieldsValues = Object.values(fields);

        for (var x = 0; x < fieldsValues.length; x++) {
          console.log(fieldsValues[x]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```